# What was the reason of birth of chaitanya mahaprabhu?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, avatars, chaitanya

What was the reason of birth of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu being an avatar of god he was not able to create huge impact on the world instead almost negligible people in the world today know him whereas common leaders of other dharmas are worldwide famous.Just born to be enlightened.This creates a doubt whether he was really an avatar of God.Neither his teachings exits nor his complete story and why was he born???

Comment: My question is different and asks if he is god or not including the one which u mentioned.

Comment: Whether He is God or Not --Who will know this? That will depend on opinion.Even the Divinity of Rama or Krishna are questioned by many! Ultimately Avatarhood is a matter of belief at least to common men.

Comment: @Pratimaputra true

Answer (score 1):

The reasons for Sri Caitanya's appearance are given in *Śrī Caitanya-caritāmṛta Ādi-līlā 3.19/20*

> yuga-dharma pravartāimu nāma-saṅkīrtana
> cāri bhāva-bhakti diyā nācāmu bhuvana
>
> āpani karimu bhakta-bhāva aṅgīkāre
> āpani ācari’ bhakti śikhāimu sabāre
>
> I shall personally inaugurate the religion of the age — nāma-saṅkīrtana, the congregational chanting of the holy name. I shall make the world dance in ecstasy, realizing the four mellows of loving devotional service.
> I shall accept the role of a devotee, and I shall teach devotional service by practicing it Myself.